# WebApp with ARM template

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I am looking for any working steps where I can create app service in azure cloud infrastructure. I followed few documentations from outsource blogs but facing some confusion

Looking forward to see any documentation of any steps.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In its current form, this question is no fit for SO. Please refer to [ask]. Also: please spend just a minute searching for an answer to your question. You will see there are many options, among which using ARM, Bicep, Terraform, Pulumi, Azure CLI, PowerShell or REST API.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample ARM template that can be created:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "webAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat('webApp-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "minLength": 2,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Web app name."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The SKU of App Service Plan."
      }
    },
    "linuxFxVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "DOTNETCORE|3.0",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Runtime stack of current web app"
      }
    },
    "repoUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": " ",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Optional Git Repo URL"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "appServicePlanPortalName": "[concat('AppServicePlan-', parameters('webAppName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('appServicePlanPortalName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
      },
      "kind": "linux",
      "properties": {
        "reserved": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",

      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanPortalName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "linuxFxVersion": "[parameters('linuxFxVersion')]"
        },
        "resources": [
          {
            "condition": "[contains(parameters('repoUrl'),'http')]",
            "type": "sourcecontrols",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "web",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('webAppName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "repoUrl": "[parameters('repoUrl')]",
              "branch": "master",
              "isManualIntegration": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There are two azure resources defined on a template:

- [**Microsoft.Web/serverfarms**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/serverfarms): create an App Service plan.
- [**Microsoft.Web/sites**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites): create an App Service app.

Later with below CLI command we can deploy the template:

```
az group create --name myResourceGroup --location "southcentralus" &&
az deployment group create --resource-group myResourceGroup --parameters webAppName="<app-name>" linuxFxVersion="PYTHON|3.7" \
--template-uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/app-service-docs-linux/azuredeploy.json"
```

For more detailed steps refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploy-web-app-to-azure-using-arm-template-5aed7331a957#:%7E:text=%20%20%201%20Step%201:%20Create%20a,deployment%20center%20should%20look%20like%20this:%20More%20) and [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-arm-template?pivots=platform-linux)